# Can I make xmlreader to use the specific encoding

Tags: c#, .net

I can specify encoding in the streamReader. I am wodnering if I cna specify encoding in the xmlReader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **StreamReader** with [XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx), which supports encoding schemes

something like this

```
var xml  = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(file, Encoding.ASCII))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. Normally, the XML file should contain an encoding at the beginning. You can override this in a StreamReader, but I guess the XmlReader just doesn't deal with that kind of thing.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood, thought you already know you can construct XmlReaders from StreamReaders.